# if else statement that checks if div class exists or not

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want an if else statement which checks if the class `.post-single` exists
and then if it exist execute code:

```
single = $('.post-single').height();
tab = $('#tab');
tab_height = tab.height();
footer_height = $('footer').height();
max_top = (single + 323) - (tab_height);
tab_offset = tab.offset();
```

and if it does not exist execute this the same code but, with a different class

```
single = $('.wrap content').height();
tab = $('#tab');
tab_height = tab.height();
footer_height = $('footer').height();
max_top = (single + 323) - (tab_height);
tab_offset = tab.offset();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the element's `length` property to check its presence,

```
if($('.post-single').length) {
 //exist
}
else {
 //not exist
}
```

Full code,

```
single =($('.post-single').length) ? $('.post-single').height() : $('.wrap content').height();  
tab = $('#tab');
tab_height = tab.height();
footer_height = $('footer').height();
max_top = (single + 323) - (tab_height);
tab_offset = tab.offset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use length property like below

```
if($(".post-single").length > 0)
  alert(".post-single exist");
```